# How to execute part of a script once?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to know if it is possible to execute one part of a big scripts only once. I mean, I have a google sheet that get the information from several google sheets, so what I would like to do it is when I create another google sheets, another source of information for the main google sheets, in insert a new line in the main google sheets and Write the rest of information there.

This is the script I have create for the new sources of information:

```
// Introduce the google sheets values into the main google sheets
  
  var ssAvance=SpreadsheetApp.openById("SHEET_ID");
  var activeSheetAvance=ssAvance.getSheetByName("Sheet_Name");
  var avanceRebarbado=app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet_Name").getRange("C6").getValue();
  var avanceFlow=app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet_Name").getRange("C7").getValue();
  var avanceDimensional=app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet_Name").getRange("C8").getValue();
  var avanceNDTAuto=app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet_Name").getRange("C9").getValue();
  var avanceNDTEvaluacion=app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet_Name").getRange("C10").getValue();  
  var avanceBocadosV900=app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet_Name").getRange("C11").getValue();
  var avanceVisualNdmV900=app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet_Name").getRange("C12").getValue();
  var avanceBocadosV1000=app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet_Name").getRange("C13").getValue();
  var avanceVisualNdmV1000=app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet_Name").getRange("C14").getValue();
  var avanceBocadosID=app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet_Name").getRange("C15").getValue();
  var avanceVisualNdmVID=app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet_Name").getRange("C16").getValue();
  var avanceTelasHDR=app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet_Name").getRange("C17").getValue();
  var avanceReparaciones=app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet_Name").getRange("C18").getValue();
  var avance2216BandasFinal=app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet_Name").getRange("C19").getValue();
  var av= app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet_Name").getRange("AF1").getValue();
//Once the values are obtein this are set in the main google sheet
  
  activeSheetAvance.getRange("A6").setValue(av);
  activeSheetAvance.getRange("B6").setValue(avanceRebarbado);
  activeSheetAvance.getRange("C6").setValue(avanceFlow);
  activeSheetAvance.getRange("D6").setValue(avanceDimensional);
  activeSheetAvance.getRange("E6").setValue(avanceNDTAuto);
  activeSheetAvance.getRange("F6").setValue(avanceNDTEvaluacion);
  activeSheetAvance.getRange("G6").setValue(avanceBocadosV900);
  activeSheetAvance.getRange("J6").setValue(avanceVisualNdmV900);
  activeSheetAvance.getRange("h6").setValue(avanceBocadosV1000);
  activeSheetAvance.getRange("K6").setValue(avanceVisualNdmV1000);
  activeSheetAvance.getRange("I6").setValue(avanceBocadosID);
  activeSheetAvance.getRange("L6").setValue(avanceVisualNdmVID);
  activeSheetAvance.getRange("M6").setValue(avanceTelasHDR);
  activeSheetAvance.getRange("N6").setValue(avanceReparaciones);
  activeSheetAvance.getRange("O6").setValue(avance2216BandasFinal);
```

As you can see in order to set the values I use a fix row, this is why I would like to know if it is posible to run only once an scripts that insert a line into the main google sheets, It should be inside this code.

Comment: Unfortunantely I cannot fully understand your issue. If you have a request that you want to perform only once - why do you not insert it into a separate function? How is the rest of your code running? On trigger? Or do you run it manually?  What exactly do you want to donly once? You want to insert a new row into the main sheet only once in your life? Or each time you create a new sheet? Please try to explain with more details, maybe provide a screenshot if helpful.

Comment: I run the code using a bottom, I one to insert only one new line when I create a new source of information that input the information in the main sheets.

Comment: As it was mentioned by others, the question is unclear, by the other hand the code is big but uncomplete. Please clarify the question and replace the current code by a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what is your goal, but your code is big because it is not optimized at all. Instead of getting one element at a time, since the range you are looking for is consecutive you can very well use `getValues` and `setValues` instead. In this way, your code will be more manageable and also way faster.

Replace your current code with:

```
function myFunction() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet_Name");
  var ssAvance=SpreadsheetApp.openById("SHEET_ID");
  var activeSheetAvance=ssAvance.getSheetByName("Sheet_Name");

  var input_data = sh.getRange('C6:C19').getValues();
  var av= sh.getRange('AF1').getValue();
  sh.getRange('A6').setValue(av);
  sh.getRange('B6:O6').setValues([input_data.flat()]);

}
```

but make sure the values in `C6:C19` correspond to the values of `B6:06`.